# Android 10 TextView animation bug

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, textview, android-10.0

I have encountered an issue, trying to animate a fragment on Android 10. I use androidx.appcompat v.1.1.0. The fragment's UI is basically an ImageView and a TextView. The fragment is supposed to slide from the bottom to the top on the screen.

While the animation is running (I see the fragment sliding upwards), the UI is rendered correctly. But as soon as the fragment reaches the top of the screen (the animation ends), the TextView disappears. Literally, text is not rendered on the screen. The issue is 100% reproducible.

Here is what I have discovered so far:

1. The issue is Android-10 specific. It can be reproduced both on the emulator and on Samsung Galaxy S10;
2. Changing the fragment's background from "#FFFF" to shape drawable with solid "#FFFF" color does nothing. However, if I add 1px stroke to the shape, the problem disappears and the TextView is rendered correctly;
3. Turning on "Draw views' borders" option in the menu helps with the issue. TextView is rendered again. It disappears again if I turn this option off.
4. Finally, setting layer type of the fragment's root view to "hardware" fixes the issue. So does setting the layer type to "software". This puzzles me the most, actually, as I initially thought it was a software rendering type of problem.

Is this a known issue? Has anyone encountered it before? My workaround of choice right now is setting the layer type to hardware, but may be there are better ways?

Comment: I would advise that you create a test project and report the problem to the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/